# Port forwarding on Windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-7, portforwarding

How do I redirect an incomming request on port xxx to localhost:yyy on windows 7?

Development Server (vs 2008) only allow access from localhost which isnt good enough. I need to test my app from various computers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions guys, although I found the answer myself.

I downloaded Microsoft SOAP Toolkit version 3 and started MSSoapT, created a formatted trace listening on port 8080, forwarding to host: 127.0.0.1 port: 3804. My problem was I used "localhost" and not "127.0.0.1".

Now every request made to my development machine from other computers through port 8080 will be redirected to port 3804 where ASP.NET Development Server is statically set to listen when debugging VS.NET webapps.

Answer (score 7):

On the command prompt.

```
$> netsh
$> interface portproxy
$> add v4tov4 listenport=xxx connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=yyy protocol=tcp
```

See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776297%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_1

Comment: This works perfect and requires no additional software to be installed!  I'm assuming, however, that it gets reset when the system restarts.  You can do this in one line (for a login script) like this `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 ...` but I don't good enough with Windows to know how to make it a system default before logging in (and running StartUp scripts).

Comment: This isn't working on my Win7 system with localhost; it works if I don't specify the connectaddress, or use the public ip as the connectaddress.  But specifying 127.0.0.1 returns no error, yet the comp is not listening on the port specified.

Answer (score 1):

If this really is for some testing, you could create a server which listens on a port, and when it receives an incoming connection spawns a thread that opens a connection to the actual local server, and afterward just waits for data to come in either end and shuffle it along to the other end. If either socket closes, the worker thread would terminate. This is obviously not a scalable solution, but for testing it should easily do the trick.

Comment: Yea, but as a developer I am lazy. So I was wondering who wrote that tool and where I can find it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are looking for. However port forwarding will be relevant when you have a router in place and you need to explicitly forward a request on a specific router port to a specific IP and port on a LAN computer. If you want to access the web server from other LAN computers on the same network then http://ip-address should just work fine. Also make sure that your web server is listening on the LAN IP and is not just bound to localhost.

Comment: Say I have a WEB application developed in VS.NET running in debug mode. This will start an application on windows called ASP.NET Development Server and will listen on, say, port 3804. Now I need a proxy/port forwarding tool of some sort to accept incomming requests on a different port, say, 8080 - and fire the request against "localhost:3804". This will force Development Server to 'think' the request came from localhost and not a remote machine. Problem is that ASP.NET Development Server only allows requests that originated from the same machine as it is running.

Comment: Cant you use just run your web app on IIS ?

Comment: If you cant install IIS on Windows 7, then probably it would be easier to install Apache and run it in proxy mode. Where Apache would serve the content from http://localhost:3804. You can easily setup Apache on window and then look into the mod_proxy module.

Comment: While developing and debugging Im testing through a mobile device also connected to my LAN, so I dont want to waste time deploying the app all the time.

Comment: Thanks, I trust your suggestion would work - It does require alot of effort to setup though. See my answer below.

Comment: great that you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using windows 7 64 bit and couldn't get the Microsoft SOAP Toolkit to work on my machine for port forwarding and didn't like the free port forwarding software I found out there so I just changed my VS 2010 web app to use local iis, I know this doesn't help people running 2008 but it works if you have 2010... Here's a screen shot of my change:   I'm doing this for testing on the iPad...

[image]