# How To Run Vagrant Apache on Port 80 on Windows and OS X

Tags: linux, windows, macos, apache, curl

### Scenario

Two host machines, one Windows, one OS X, both running Vagrant and Virtualbox.

### Problem

VirtualBox on Mac cannot bind to ports below 1024 without root access.
Don't know how to port forward port on Windows machine

### Symptoms

- Apache running perfectly on both machines
- Mac can access site.local:8080 and use pfctl to access this on site.local
- Windows machine can access site.local:8080 or site.local:80 (no port forwarding)
- curl site.local on guest machine returns expected output
- curl site.local on host machine returns connection refused
- iptables on host machine dis
- Port forwarding guest port 80 to host port 80 on Mac *was working* until today. Don't know how or why. Stopped for some reason.

### Question

1. How can I force VirtualBox to run as root on port 80 (regarded as a bad idea)
2. Alternatively, how can I setup port forwarding on the Windows machine so that site.local:8080 is accessible at site.local?
3. Alternatively, how can I setup an OS-specific Vagrantfile that can be version controlled.

### What I've tried

- http://gielberkers.com/fixing-vagrant-port-forwarding-osx-yosemite/ - Works
- [Port forwarding on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721000/port-forwarding-on-windows-7) - Doesn't work
- Enabling config.vm.network "public_network" and binding to en0 gives this error:

  ```
  ==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
  The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
  Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
  ARPCHECK=no /sbin/ifup eth1 2> /dev/null
  Stdout from the command:
  Determining IP information for eth1... failed.
  Stderr from the command:
  ```

### Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = “devbox”
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision.sh"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 443

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  config.vm.network "public_network"

  # If true, then any SSH connections made will enable agent forwarding.
  # Default value: false
  # config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Don't boot with headless mode
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
  #   vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you're using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with CFEngine. CFEngine Community packages are
  # automatically installed. For example, configure the host as a
  # policy server and optionally a policy file to run:
  #
  # config.vm.provision "cfengine" do |cf|
  #   cf.am_policy_hub = true
  #   # cf.run_file = "motd.cf"
  # end
  #
  # You can also configure and bootstrap a client to an existing
  # policy server:
  #
  # config.vm.provision "cfengine" do |cf|
  #   cf.policy_server_address = "10.0.2.15"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with Puppet stand alone.  Puppet manifests
  # are contained in a directory path relative to this Vagrantfile.
  # You will need to create the manifests directory and a manifest in
  # the file default.pp in the manifests_path directory.
  #
  # config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
  #   puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
  #   puppet.manifest_file  = "default.pp"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with chef solo, specifying a cookbooks path, roles
  # path, and data_bags path (all relative to this Vagrantfile), and adding
  # some recipes and/or roles.
  #
  # config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
  #   chef.cookbooks_path = "../my-recipes/cookbooks"
  #   chef.roles_path = "../my-recipes/roles"
  #   chef.data_bags_path = "../my-recipes/data_bags"
  #   chef.add_recipe "mysql"
  #   chef.add_role "web"
  #
  #   # You may also specify custom JSON attributes:
  #   chef.json = { mysql_password: "foo" }
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with chef server, specifying the chef server URL,
  # and the path to the validation key (relative to this Vagrantfile).
  #
  # The Opscode Platform uses HTTPS. Substitute your organization for
  # ORGNAME in the URL and validation key.
  #
  # If you have your own Chef Server, use the appropriate URL, which may be
  # HTTP instead of HTTPS depending on your configuration. Also change the
  # validation key to validation.pem.
  #
  # config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
  #   chef.chef_server_url = "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/ORGNAME"
  #   chef.validation_key_path = "ORGNAME-validator.pem"
  # end
  #
  # If you're using the Opscode platform, your validator client is
  # ORGNAME-validator, replacing ORGNAME with your organization name.
  #
  # If you have your own Chef Server, the default validation client name is
  # chef-validator, unless you changed the configuration.
  #
  #   chef.validation_client_name = "ORGNAME-validator"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use following string in config file:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
```

https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html

in additional you need to enable Public Network in the Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html

If that doesnt help, may you please show your Vagrantfile?

Comment: Tried the former. Hadn't enabled public_network in the past. Added Vagrantfile to original question.

Comment: Hi, I tryed to use your Vagrantfile (just changed two following strings)   `config.vm.box = "chef/ubuntu-14.04"` and
  `config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt-get install -y apache2"` and everythong works i can see apache landing page in browser in host computer (win8.0) by adress [http://localhost](http://localhost) without problems. please check that port 80 is free in host system.

Comment: Nothing running on port 80 on the host system. If there was I don't think the VM would boot without displaying an error would it?